# How to get a javascript function working inside a php table?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to get the `Multiply` function to run and multiply the Order Quantity times the item price. I cannot get the function to run inside the PHP loop using the `oninput` attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">             
    function Multiply() {
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('editedvalues[]').value; 
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('price').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
        result.value = myResult;
    }
</script>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT item_price.item_id,
               item_price.ITEM_NAME,
               suggested_qty,
               Price_item
        FROM item_price
        JOIN suggested_item ON item_price.ITEM_NAME = suggested_item.ITEM_NAME";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>

form action="#" method="post">
<tr>
<th> ID</th>
<th>Item Name</th>
<th>Suggested Quantity</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>OrderQuanity</th>
<th>Total Cost</th>

</tr>
<?php

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['item_id']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['ITEM_NAME']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['suggested_qty']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['Price_item']}</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='editedvalues[]' value='{$row['suggested_qty']}' oninput='Multiply()' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input name='result' /></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: why don't you just do it in PHP? $result = $row['Price_item'] * $row['suggested_qty']; and in result column echo $result

Comment: Oh ok - you want to have it on user input.

Comment: You should also not be using inline event handlers like `oninput` any more. Use a proper event binding method in a separate script file or element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `document.getElementById` function to refer to elements, but in addition to the fact that there are multiple inputs that this function can run on, your inputs don't even have an ID.

To make sure this function works on the input in question, you'll need to look at the target of the event instead of ignoring it. As well, you should use proper event binding instead of inline `oninput` attributes.

You also weren't using a `table` element, and you should really break out of PHP for huge blocks of HTML code.

This would be much easier using some framework like jQuery, but this should work.

```js
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("qtyinput");

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].addEventListener('input', multiply, false);
}

function multiply(e) {
    var qty = e.target.value; 
    var price = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("pricetd")[0].textContent;
    var result = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("resultinput")[0];
    var myResult = qty * price;
    result.value = myResult;
}
```

```html
<?php
$sql = "SELECT item_price.item_id,
               item_price.ITEM_NAME,
               suggested_qty,
               Price_item
        FROM item_price
        JOIN suggested_item ON item_price.ITEM_NAME = suggested_item.ITEM_NAME";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th> ID</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Suggested Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>OrderQuanity</th>
        <th>Total Cost</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- test data for snippet -->
    <tr>
        <td>111</td>
        <td>Test item</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td class="pricetd">40</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="editedvalues[]" class="qtyinput" value="4" />
        </td>
        <td><input name='result' class="resultinput" /></td>
    </tr>

    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) :?>

    <tr>
        <td><?=$row["item_id"]?></td>
        <td><?=$row["ITEM_NAME"]?></td>
        <td><?=$row["suggested_qty"]?></td>
        <td class="pricetd"><?=$row["Price_item"]?></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="editedvalues[]" class="qtyinput" value="<?=$row["suggested_qty"]?>" />
        </td>
        <td><input name='result' class="resultinput" /></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile?>

    </table>
<form>
```